# What is the meaning of 'Ina-lilahi-wa-ina-rajiun'?

Tags: islamic-basis, dhikr

In the Bangladeshi community when one hears of some tragedy they recite '*Ina-lilahi-wa-ina-rajiun*' (I'm not sure that I've transcribed that correctly.)  Where does this phrase come from, and what does it mean, and how is it written in Arabic?

Comment: [Google it](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=inna+lillah+rajioon+dua&oq=inna+lil&gs_l=serp.3.0.0l4.873113.1039131.0.1040996.8.8.0.0.0.0.228.1078.1j6j1.8.0....0...1c.1.25.serp..1.7.926.trqsQxlIe6w)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inna_Lillahi_wa_inna_ilaihi_raji%27un):

> Inna lillahi wa inna ilayhi raji'un (إِنَّا لِلّهِ وَإِنَّـا إِلَيْهِ رَاجِعونَ) is a verse of the Quran which means Surely we belong to Allah and to Him shall we return.
>
> This phrase is recited by Muslims when a person is struck by calamity in life, and is also recited upon hearing the death news of a Muslim. This can also be recited in any situation involving risk of any sort.

It is taken directly from the following ayah of the Qur'an:

> الذين إذا أصابتهم مصيبة قالوا **إنا لله وإنا إليه راجعون**
> Who, when disaster strikes them, say, "**Indeed we belong to Allah , and indeed to Him we will return.**"
> <sup>—[Al-Baqarah 156](http://quran.com/2/156)—</sup>